# How to get image Data properly?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to take photo and return image data as return type of function. AVFoundation takes picture asynchronous, and my function returns before it's finished, so I get empty bytes.

I tried calling takePicture() with waiting, as said in this reply [Waiting until the task finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484281/waiting-until-the-task-finishes) but it just freezes UI.

```
func takePicture() -> Data {

    var imageData: Data?

        self.stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection!, completionHandler: { (imageDataBuffer, error) in

            if let result = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: imageDataBuffer!, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: imageDataBuffer!) {
                imageData = result
            }

            // Removing sessions and stop running
        })

    return imageData!
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for async function return value in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861337/wait-for-async-function-return-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion

```
func takePicture(completion:@escaping(Data?) -> ()) {
    self.stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection!, completionHandler: { (imageDataBuffer, error) in
        if let result = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: imageDataBuffer!, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: imageDataBuffer!) {
            completion(result)
        }
        else {
              completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```